# while entering add odbc dsn details using powershell command prompt dsn type not executing

Tags: powershell

while entering

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name $ODBCConnectionName -DriverName "Amazon Redshift (x64)" -DsnType "System" -Platform '64-bit' -SetPropertyValue @("Server=$DBHostname","port=$Port", "Database=$DBName","User=$USER","Password=$Password")
```

not executing no error

Comment: PLEASE ... [1] wrap your code in code formatting markers. the page you used to enter your Question has links to the HowTo for that. ///// [2] DO NOT post images of code/data/errors. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: There is a password in the screenshot you provided. Please make sure it's not valid!

Answer (score 1):

The `Set-OdbcDsn` command has no output when successful. Check that it completed successfully with

```
Get-OdbcDsn -Name $ODBCConnectionName -DsnType System
```

Some issues you might see though:

- You must be running as an administrator to create `System` type DSNs
- If you create a `User` type DSN, *only* the user running the command will be able to see it
- Many applications only check for new DSNs on startup, and will need to be restarted

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But i have tried same thing you have mentioned Get-OdbcDsn -Name $ODBCConnectionName -DsnType System still running / script in bottom. no output.

Comment: I have tried the below one

Comment: PS C:\Users\*******> Add-OdbcDsn
cmdlet Add-OdbcDsn at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: sample
DriverName: Amazon Redshift (x64)
DsnType: System after no output and no error

Comment: @CHANDRA try `Get-OdbcDsn -type System` (without a name) and see what the full list you have looks like. It should have output even if it's empty I think

Comment: I have tried getting the below error. Get-OdbcDsn -type System
Get-OdbcDsn : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'type'.
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-OdbcDsn -type System
+             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-OdbcDsn], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Get-OdbcDsn

Comment: @CHANDRA sorry, it was a typo. Try `Get-OdbcDsn` on its own, or `Get-OdbcDsn -DsnType System`